# How can I compile an Android kernel with root permission?

Tags: android, kernel, root, android-source, privileges

I have successfully compiled an AOSP branch (andriod 5.1.1) and installed it to my nexus 5. I have also recompiled a new kernel and replaced the former kernel. I want to know if it is possible to gain root privilege by modify the kernel source code. If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: did you succeeded compiling Android kernel with root permission?

Answer (score 1):

in build/core/main.mk find block:

```
ifneq (,$(user_variant))
  # Target is secure in user builds.
  ADDITIONAL_DEFAULT_PROPERTIES += ro.secure=1
```

change ro.secure=0